# Export Lottie animation as a layer by AVVideoComposition

Tags: ios, avfoundation, core-animation, video-processing, lottie

I want to add an animated sticker to an iOS video and export it through AVVideoComposition. I am able to do it by using a Lottie animation, but the problem is while exporting the Lottie animation as a layer in AVvideocoreanimationtool it is not properly synced with the video timing. The animation speed is variable in different device while exporting. The animation is actually not rendered correctly depending on device, etc.

The animation timespace is not linked to the video timespace. I know there is an easy solution that is take screenshot and add it in video layer but it's costly. Any suggestion how to solve this problem and use Lottie as a layer and export video efficiently?

Comment: @mayqiyue I opened an issue in lottie git repository and they added this as a feature request.Hope that they will bring this feature soon in live.Here is the Link 
https://github.com/airbnb/lottie-ios/issues/1001

Comment: Look's like it never happened